# Как получить количество записей в курсоре?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-cursor

Xотел бы получить количество записей в курсоре. Есть ли ключевое слово, которое может помочь?

Используя это количество, необходимо построить логику при считывании записей.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to find number of rows in cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4934134) от участника [@Avi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515756/avi)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/4934134

Answer (score 2):

Нет, такого свойства или функции у курсора нет. В общем случае, неизвестно, сколько записей верннёт курсор.

Иногда предлaгаается решение, выполнить запрос дважды, один раз с `COUNT`, а второй раз для получения записей - неверно, так как между двумя запросами кол-во записей может изменится.

Атрибут курсора `cursor_variable%rowcount` возвращает кол-во записей, которые уже считаны во всех выполненых, включая *текущий*, `FETCH`, то есть с `INTO` (одиночное считывание) всегда плюс один:

В качестве решения, можно "вынудить" БД посчитать все записи в выборке оконной функцией `COUNT`:

```
declare
    cursor cur is 
       select object_name, count(*) over () total from user_objects;
    name varchar2(128);
    total int;
begin 
    open cur;
    fetch cur into name, total; 
    dbms_output.put_line ('rowcont='||cur%rowcount||' total '||total||' rows');
end;
```

> rowcount=1 total 942 rows

Или, что самое простое, считать все записи в одном `FETCH BULK COLLECT INTO`. Конечно, это возможно только для сравнительно небольшого кол-ва записей, которые вернёт курсор:

```
declare
    cursor cur is 
       select object_name from user_objects;
    type rowarr is table of varchar2(128) index by pls_integer;
    rows rowarr;
begin 
    open cur;
    dbms_output.put_line ('rowcont='||cur%rowcount);
    fetch cur bulk collect into rows; 
    dbms_output.put_line ('rowcount='||cur%rowcount||' total '||rows.count||' rows');
    for i in 1..rows.count loop 
        null; /*здесь логика считывания*/ end loop;
end;
```

> rowcount=942 total 942 rows